Error loading discovery document: Issuer name is missing
I'm having an runtime error with oidcClient.LoginAsync().In my solution there are 9 projects. To configure auth0 I have to add Auth0-OidcClient-WinForms package for the server related project. After adding it I have to migrate the packages.config file to packageReferences to work with installed package.
In this process Auth0 worked fine without having any issue. But when I build the setup.exe file. I was getting runtime error related to assembly binding in app.config file. So I have migrate whole other project from package.config to packageReferences.
After this change I'm getting Error loading discovery document: Issuer name is missing issue.
I have added the stacktrace and the code I have used bellow.
{System.InvalidOperationException: Error loading discovery document: Issuer name is missing
   at IdentityModel.OidcClient.OidcClient.<EnsureProviderInformationAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityModel.OidcClient.OidcClient.<EnsureConfigurationAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityModel.OidcClient.OidcClient.<LoginAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Auth0.OidcClient.Auth0ClientBase.<LoginAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Server.Presenters.ServerConnectPresenter.<View_ContinueClicked>d__26.MoveNext() in C:\Users\test\Documents\Build-Issue\New test\myproject\Server\Presenters\ServerConnectPresenter.cs:line 327}

var options = new Auth0ClientOptions
{
   ClientId = Constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
   Domain = Constants.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
};

var oidcClient = new Auth0Client(options);
var result = await oidClient.LoginAsync();

Nuget package: Auth0-OidcClient-WinForms
Version: 3.5.0
Platform Version: NET Framework 4.7.2
